# Class variable vs reference to parent in python

Tags: python, class, variables, reference, parent

I have a style question.
Is it a bad idea to use a reference of a "manager object" to manage shared variables between objects?

```
class Profile_Line:
    def __init__(self, parent, line):
        self.parent = parent
        self.line = line

    def get_results(self):
        image = self.parent.image # Is this a good idea?
        profile_line = self.get_profile_line(image, self.line)
        return profile_line

    def get_profile_line(self,img,line):
        return [1,2,3,4] #not real function


class Profile_Line_Manager():
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.p_lines = []  # a list of Profile Line objects

    def add_profile_line(self, line):
        self.p_lines.append(Profile_Line(self, line))

    def get_results(self):
        for pl in self.p_lines:
            print(pl.get_results())
```

So there is a class Profile Line, which calculates some values with its own parameters as well with the image, which it gets through the manager.
The image is the same for all profile lines, which belong to the same manager.
So a class variable cant be used, since all profile_line objects would have the same image, even if they don't belong together.

Is it a good idea to pass the parent object to the profile line objects, which belong to that manager? It feels kind of weird.
Or is there a better way of doing this, e.g. integrating both classes into one.

Comment: That first `def get_results` is significantly broken somehow. Either it's not indented correctly, and/or it's unclear where its `parent` comes from.

Comment: Thanks, the parent was ment to be the instance variable "self.parent". The function get_profile_line doesnt exist yet, but lets assume it just returns some List of Integers.

Comment: Still incorrect indentation and missing `self`…!?

Comment: It is but I can't edit it because it's too little edits to submit. Can you try?

Comment: Oh my bad, better now? :)

Comment: Yah. Also, why can't the `Image` be a class variable? It seems the same image is being used for **all** profile line instances, just that you're referencing them from the parent instead of itself. Or do you have multiple managers with different images?...

Comment: Exactly, there might be several managers with different images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with integrating the classes. The only things you'd lose (as far as I can tell) is batch generating instances with the same `image`, and a list of all the instances that do have the same `image`. For this, I'd recommend a function:

```
profile_lines = []
def generate_profile_lines (image, lines): 
    # image will be whatever it was before, line will be a list since you (seem to) want to have multiple instances with different lines and the same image
    global profile_lines
    profile_lines.append ([Profile_Line (image, line) for line in lines])
```

As you probably noticed, I passed in `image` to `Profile_Line`. This is because I think you should restructure it to accept `image` as a parameter.

Comment: This way, each sub-list of the global `profile_lines` will have their own image -- kind of like your manager.

Comment: I see, but if the image changes, I would have to change it for every profile_line. What about integrating the other way around and let the manager handle the line on his own. That means putting the functions "get_results" into the manager and let him loop over the lines?

Comment: The v ariable "image" of the manager class could directly be changed from outside, because it is not marked as private "_".

Comment: Would you like me to make a function to do that?

Comment: No, thats not necessary thanks! I was just looking for the best solution from a structure point of view.

Comment: You do not like the idea of handling the lines in one class line_manager?

Comment: Nah, it kinda goes against the zen of python -- don't make things too complicated for no reason. And btw, I will edit my answer to add the function I mentioned before, because why not? :)